# How to set the page size for printing in Java using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to set the page size for printing. This is the output I'm getting:

[image: Output I'm getting]

This is the output I want:

[image: Output I want]

Here is my code:

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setJobName("Print Data");
        
    job.setPrintable(new Printable(){
        public int print(Graphics pg,PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            if(pageNum > 0){
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            g2.scale(1,1);
            
            jPanel3.print(g2);
     
           return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS; 
        }
    });
    boolean ok = job.printDialog();
    if(ok){
        try{
            job.print();
        }
        catch (PrinterException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Do check my code and tell me how to get the expected output

Comment: Unless your image is the size of a standard size sheet of paper, you're going to have to place the image on the page where you want it.  You print jPanel3 to a BufferedImage, then draw the BufferedImage on the page using the Graphics2D drawImage method.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can't we have custom page format? Ex. 150*100cm which will be the size of final output?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can you provide code for writing jPanel3 to BufferedImage

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can you tell me how can I print this returned image. With size 250*200cm. This will solve my entire problem. Like the final pdf which will get print is also of same size not A4

Comment: Sure.  Tell me how many pixels per centimeter your printer prints.

Comment: An A4 sheet of paper is 210mm x 297mm.  Your image, assuming you meant millimeters, barely fits on the page,  I'd use at least a 20 mm margin on all sides, leaving you a maximum of 257mm x 170mm for your image.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image of any size you wish.  If you actually want to print the image on a standard piece of paper, then the standard piece of paper will be a standard size.

The best you can do is enlarge or shrink the image so it fits on the printed page.

This is a method I wrote to paint my JPanel to a BufferedImage.  The method is part of the JPanel class.

```
private BufferedImage getBufferedImage() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            getWidth(), getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    paintAll(g);
    g.dispose();
    
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I print this returned image. With size 250*200cm. This will solve my entire problem. Like the final pdf which will get print is also of same size not A4